# android- Scroll View

Tags: android

My application need to display scroll view under scroll view. I implemented it but it works only in the simulator. it not works in the device because device supports only touch not scroll.

Is it possible in the device?
if yes, how to implement it

thanks

Comment: Which kind of device is that? Android devices have to support scroll.

Comment: It doesn't make sense at all to have the touch working and the scroll not working. Perhaps is it broken?

Comment: Scrollview inside a scrollview is not a good practice. You will certainly have problems. You should try to change your layout.

Comment: touch is working for main scroll view and it is not working for sub scroll view. if you touch on the sub scroll view that also considered as a main scroll view.

Comment: Hi bala, then how to implement two scroll views in a single layout

Comment: It's ambiguous for the application to know which scroll view you want to scroll. Hence the problem. What kind of a layout are you trying to create?

Comment: i tried another one option, List view under in scrollview, suppose i have more then one item in list view scrolling is not working. please help me.

Comment: Well list view scrolls too. So you'll face the same problem. Its not really clear to me what kind of a UI you are trying to create.

Comment: I am using more than 5 text view and one listview. this two in one scrollview, so outside scrollbar working. when more than one items in listview, i can't see others items. so how to show other items of the listview. i think now it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Linearlayout
|——-ListView
|——-ScrollView
     |——-TextView1
     |——-TextView2
     ...
```

I think something like this should work

Comment: Linearlayout
    |——-ScrollView
      |——-Linearlayout
            |---Text View
               ,Linearlayout
               ,Linearlayout,
               ----------             
               ,Linearlayout
                   |----List view.                                    
can you check is it work?

Comment: Can't really understand the hierarchy from your comment

Comment: Linear Layout have one scrollview that scrollview contains textview and some Linear layouts among these linear layouts one Linear Layout have List View.This is the hierarchy. i think it is clear now.

Comment: Since there's a list view inside the scrollview's children hierarchy, You should pull it out.

Comment: My requirement is it possible or not?

Comment: It's not that it's impossible. But the solutions may be hackish and there's no guarantee that it will work properly. Here's a solution to have a listview inside scrollview that I found http://nex-otaku-en.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-put-listview-in-scrollview.html